# How do I print my list of numbers in python without "set" before it? With a function where it returns a new list & the numbers only occur once

Tags: python, list, numbers, set

I have defined a function that takes a list of numbers and returns a new list where each element of the first list only occurs once.

```
def unique(a):
      return set(a)

print unique([1,2,3,4,1,5])
```

I tried `print ",".join(str(e) for e in s)` but it doesn't work because I have to print a new list where there is no repeated numbers.

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work" means? I don't understand that sentence. Is it just that you forgot to use `unique(s)` in place of `s` there? Or something different? Can you show us the input, intended output, and actual output you got from the code you tried?

Comment: If the issue is just that a `set` isn't a `list`, that's easy: `return list(set(a))`. But somehow I don't think that's your problem here.

Comment: Indeed, it sounds like as @abarnert suggested you simply forgot to use the `set` as `s` and instead used the raw input list. Note that your ``unique`` method does *not* maintain input order, and a ``set`` is not a ``list``, for example it doesn't support indexing (``set[0]`` is not allowed). At minimum if order doesn't matter it should be returning ``list(set(a))``, but if you need to maintain input order than you need to do something different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
list(set(a))
```

This will convert the list to a set, which will keep only unique occurrences, then convert back to a list.

Example:

```
>>> list(set([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]))
[1, 2, 3]
```